# I made photos of plants in a garden. On which SE site may I ask what they are?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I took some photos of plants in a garden, and I'm trying to improve that garden.

On which SE site may I ask what the plants are?
My guess is "Biology" or maybe "Home Improvement", but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you need to make the plants in the garden nice, or the photo of them nice?  (http://photo.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Would [Gardening and Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) make sense?

The site is stable and [went out of Beta](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/883/congratulations-youre-no-longer-in-beta) in October 2019, so likely the most relevant place.

Comment: If true, then I think that for future searches, the textual description should be very precise. Otherwise it would be too localized, I think. (Not every question has a place on Stack Exchange, @winerd.)

Comment: ID of plants in pictures seems to be on topic there. (I actually won a prize for my answer there on such a question.)

Comment: @Arjan "identification ... of ... weeds" is listed in the _Gardening and Landscaping_ FAQ as question to ask. Thanks Aaron.